# looking for a random img

Tags: c#, html

I want to look for a image on a webbrowser, but that image is random and the url where that image is located is also random. 
The url start always the same but it has always 10 random number added to it.
is there a way to check for this random img?

Answer (score 0):

You can look through some random urls with python and uf it finds so. This code bellow was used to download IMG from 0 to 7000 of a webpage. try it out with a random string as x.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import URLError

def download_web_image(url3,name):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url3,name)

x = 0
while x<7000:
    url="https://xxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/"
    url2=".jpg"
    url3=url+str(x)+url2
    name=str(x)+".jpg"

    try:
        download_web_image(url3,name)

    except URLError as e:
        print ("")

    print(url3)
    x += 1
```